# Taleo Password field alignment issue

Tags: taleo

I am trying to modify layout of Taleo career website pages to match with my organisation look and feel. I have business addition of Taleo with trial access.

While designing Job Application form with `Password` field, it adds `Re-type new password`  automatically, but the alignment/layout is not proper for `Re-type new password` input field. Please refer attached sceenshot of UI.

[Re-type new Password alignment issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8wl6.png).

Does any one has encountered similar issues while working with Taleo? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.